# Write folder name and subfolder name being deleted to output file

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have written the below with the intention of deleting all folders in a directory that have a creation date of 2 days or more and log this in an output file if it is successful or not.

The script works as I would like with the exception that the name of the file will not show in the output file. All that is displayed is 'Deletion of Failed/Successful'

```cs
$dump_path = "C:\desktop"
$max_days = "-2"
$curr_date = Get-Date
$del_date = $curr_date.AddDays($max_days)

ForEach-Object {
  $filename = $_
  Get-ChildItem $statfolder\$_ -Recurse | Where-Object {
    $_.CreationTime -lt $del_date
  } | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force

  if ($? -eq $false) {
    echo "$Deletion of $filename Failed" |
      Out-File -Append C:\Logs\DELETION_FAIL_K_$(Get-Date -Format `"dd-MMM-yyyy`").txt
  } else {
    Write-Output "Deletion of $filename Successful" |
      Out-File -Append C:\Logs\DELETION_SUCCESS_K_$(Get-Date -format `"dd-MMM-yyyy`").txt
  }
}
```

I would ideally like the log to display the parent folder name and a list of the sub folders in next level down only. Is this possible?

Eg. the log would read

> Deletion of folder **12-Jan-2017** containing sub folders **R2015, R2086** was Successful

If the sub folders in the next level cannot be added then just the below would be great:

> Deletion of folder **12-Jan-2017** was Successful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you're using `ForEach-Object` the current object variable `$_` (and consequentially the variable `$filename`) is never populated. Where would you expect the value to come from?

Feed the output of `Get-ChildItem | Where-Object` into `ForEach-Object`, but sort the results by full name first, so that nested folders are deleted before their parents.

```
Get-ChildItem $statfolder\$_ -Recurse | Where-Object {
  $_.PSIsContainer -and
  $_.CreationTime -lt $del_date
} | Sort-Object FullName | ForEach-Object {
  $folder = $_.FullName
  "Deleting folder '$folder'."
  Remove-Item $folder -Recurse -Force -WhatIf
}
```

With the `-WhatIf` switch present you'll be doing a dry-run, just echoing what would be deleted without actually deleting it. After you verified that everything would work as intended remove the switch and re-run.

Comment: This works great the out put now shows  \\lonimpdat02\IT$\Room_Deletion_Tool\Roomstobedeleted\10-Jan-2017 Deletion Successful

Any ideas how to show the contents of the next directory level that was deleted?

Comment: That would require enumerating its content first. Consider this your homework.

Comment: I will a look and see where I get! Thanks for the help

Comment: Im not having much luck with enumerating its content first, can you point me in the right direction to set me off?

Comment: Think a moment about what `Get-ChildItem` does.